# How to configure Inno Setup to check for Visual C++ Redistributable Packages

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, exe, inno-setup

I've created a Javafx 2 application, of relatively compact size,  which is a lending library with database for free use in public primary schools. I have installed the Inno Setup and WiX and my application works well.
I package my application (using presets) with an exe installer (inno setup).
However, when I try to install my application on different Windows computers, I noticed that it was running well only in those computers that had fully updated their Windows version.

On computers where due to low RAM the auto update of Win XP was disabled I receive an error during the installation of my application - namely, that the file msvcr100.dll was missing. When I manually update the system by installing the Microsoft visual C ++ X86 10.0.40219, then, for some computers, the application ran, but slowly, and the menu options and buttons of my application were periodically frozen. On other computers I received a JaxaFx runtime exception.

How can I customize the installer so that before installing my application it  checks the target operating system for required dependencies, and automatically install them?

Comment: lot of thanks to Fluffmeister for edit my document

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question for which there is probably no good solution for your use-case.  It seems the underlying issue has been fixed for Java 8u40:

- [RT-37178 The Windows launcher generated by the packager fails to load msvcr100.dll on 32-bit OS](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37178)

So, you could package using the Java 8u40 release when that comes out.  This does mean that you would not be able to target Windows XP computers (at least using a runtime which is officially supported by Oracle), because [only Windows 7 and later are official targets of Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html).

Comment: It can not happen. When using a technology to produce a software, then it should be installed with no errors to the client computer, even if he has some common problems.
Jewelsea thank you for your reply and your instructions.