# What xp dependencies is necessary for running a self-contained javafx application?

Tags: java, javafx, installation, self-contained

When a self-contained package javafx application is run well in win xp and installed in other win xp computer and I received a JavaFx runtime exception; what dependencies of xp must be missing for producing this error message.

Comment: Which version of JRE is installed in other computers?

Comment: What was the exception? Note that Windows XP is not a supported platform for Java (or, really, [for anything](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx)).

Comment: Also see earlier question from Farmer: [How to configure Inno Setup to check for Visual C++ Redistributable Packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572217/how-to-configure-inno-setup-to-check-for-visual-c-redistributable-packages).  XP is not a supported platform - attempting to build a JavaFX application which targets XP is not advised.

Comment: 1) None JRE is installed in other computers, because the javafx application in the installation package (create by netbeans 8, with inno setup 5) has inside the JRE who is needed.
2) The Exception is: JavaFX launcher Error --> Exception while running application.